# Non-existing element on page

Tags: java, webdriver

Happy New Year and need first assistance in this year. I created following loop:

```
 ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('" + href + "','_blank');");
if (!userName.equals(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//be-user//div[contains(@class, 'be-user__name')]")).getText())) {
            System.out.println("Failed");
        }
        else{
        System.out.println("Profile correctly shown");
        }
```

Also, one very important thing: do not want to test fail since that I have a list with 30 elements and want to check them all (if i.e first does not exist, then go to next element)
But, now I have the case (which did not count on it) to open page for previously deleted user (So, actually first line open page in new tab and after opened, looks for an element on that page) - in summary **driver.findelement** does not found anything and my test fails, with following results:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element:   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//be-user//div[contains(@class, 'be-user__name')]"}
```

And to short this long story, could you please help me to find solution - 
if element does not exist could I just return to previous page and does

> isEmpty

will solve the case (to creating another **if** loop):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//be-user//div[contains(@class, 'be-user__name')]")).isEmpty;
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are talking about, but just so you know: an if-statement is not a loop.

Comment: Yes, thank you @Stultuske

Answer (score 0):

Found solution myself:

```
driver.findElements( By.xpath("...") ).size() != 0
```